# How do I store XML attribute (with the XML value passing some test) in a XSL variable?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Having the following xml:

```
<countries>
  <country id="1">Andora</country>
  <country id="2">Bulgaria</country>
  <country id="3">Croatia</country>
  <country id="4">Danemark</country>
  <country id="5">Estonia</country>
</countries>
```

how can I store the "@id" attribute of Andora in a xsl:variable? Something like

```
<xsl:variable name="andora_id" select=???????>
```

so that I can use the "$andora_id" with value of "1" later in the rest of my xsl?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution that is slightly more reliable than the currently accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I store the "@id" attribute of
>   Andora in a xsl:variable? Something
>   like
>
> ```
> <xsl:variable name="andora_id" select=???????>
> ```
>
> so that I can use the "$andora_id"
>   with value of "1" later in the rest of
>   my xsl?

This is actually an XPath question.

**Use**:

```
<xsl:variable name="andora_id" select="/*/country[.='Andora']/@id"/>
```

This defines an `xsl:variable` named `andora_id` whose value is the node-set of all `id` attributes of any `country` element that is a child of the top element of the XML document and whose string value is `'Andora'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:variable name="andora_id" 
              select="/countries/country[text() = 'Andora']/@id" />
```

Comment: Correct answer, but that node set comparison with text nodes children can end up in wrong results. It's better to use string value

Comment: I think the answer of Dimitre is more correct; you have a +1 from me, but I'll mark his one as the accepted one.